# Convertir un array en un objeto en Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente arreglo de un servicio

```
[
  {
    key: 'name',
    label: 'first name',
    defaultValue: null,
    type: 'text'
  },
  {
    key: 'address',
    label: 'main addres',
    defaultValue: null,
    type: 'text'
  },
  {
    key: 'phone',
    label: 'Number Phone',
    defaultValue: null,
    type: 'number'
  }
]
```

Y quiero generar un objeto con la siguiente estructura, usando algún tipo de ciclo o método de arreglos:

```
{

  key: [defaultValue, type],
  key: [defaultValue, type],
  key: [defaultValue, type]
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Qué error tienes? Pon un ejemplo claro del resultado esperado, el ejemplo que pones no es interpretable: ¿qué significa `key`, qué significa `defaultValue`, qué significa `type`? ¿El servicio que consultas no tiene un modo de consulta que mande los resultados organizados de la forma esperada?

Comment: Usa [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) para generar el objeto, es relativamente sencillo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto te puede servir. Tendrías que recorrer el array y crear un objecto dinámico.

```js
var x = [
  {
    key: 'name',
    label: 'first name',
    defaultValue: null,
    type: 'text'
  },
  {
    key: 'address',
    label: 'main addres',
    defaultValue: null,
    type: 'text'
  },
  {
    key: 'phone',
    label: 'Number Phone',
    defaultValue: null,
    type: 'number'
  }
]
const $object = {}
x.forEach((item)=>{
    $object[item.key] = [item.defaultValue,item.type];
})
console.log($object);
```